# How to install specific version of mariadb-server (10.3.22)

Tags: apt, software-installation

I've got to install mariadb-server-10.3.22 but when I try to find out the packet using `apt list mariadb-server -a` command, it returns two available packages:

```
mariadb-server/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 1:10.3.34-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 all
mariadb-server/focal,focal 1:10.3.22-1ubuntu1 all
```

How can I install the second one `mariadb-server/focal,focal 1:10.3.22-1ubuntu1 all`?

Comment: Why would you need this? It is possible, but you'll have to disable system updates. It may cause all sorts of trouble later. Is that `22` minor version so important?

Answer (score 0):

You may already figured out the answer, but I will add my musings here: one needs to append the package version *fully* as you saw them in your query, and, in this case we also need to include the mariadb 10.3.22 client package dependencies, in a format like this (as on April 12th, 2023):

```
apt install mariadb-server-10.3=1:10.3.22-1ubuntu1 mariadb-server-core-10.3=1:10.3.22-1ubuntu1 mariadb-client-10.3=1:10.3.22-1ubuntu1 mariadb-client-core-10.3=1:10.3.22-1ubuntu1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libxmlb1
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  galera-3 libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libconfig-inifiles-perl libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libencode-locale-perl libfcgi-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl
  libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libsnappy1v5 libterm-readkey-perl libtimedate-perl liburi-perl mariadb-common socat
Suggested packages:
  libclone-perl libmldbm-perl libnet-daemon-perl libsql-statement-perl libdata-dump-perl libipc-sharedcache-perl libwww-perl mailx mariadb-test tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  galera-3 libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libconfig-inifiles-perl libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libencode-locale-perl libfcgi-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl
  libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libsnappy1v5 libterm-readkey-perl libtimedate-perl liburi-perl mariadb-client-10.3 mariadb-client-core-10.3 mariadb-common mariadb-server-10.3 mariadb-server-core-10.3 socat
0 upgraded, 25 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.
Need to get 29.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 222 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I hope it helps, and no worries, it took me a dozen of minutes to figure out the correct versions for Ubuntu focal ;-)

```
lsb_release -a
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```